# How to go from a discriminated union representation of a type to a System type for arrays?

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

In F#, if I want to create a `System.Type` of say, an array of strings, I could just write `typeof<string[]>` and be done with it. That is because I can specify the type in the `typeof` at compile time.

```
type Ty =
| Int32
| Float32
| String
| Array of Ty

let to_dotnet_type: Ty -> System.Type = ...
```

But suppose I had an union type so that the exact `System.Type` I am looking for is unknown at compile time, how would I go from `Ty` to the .NET `System.Type`? Arrays in particular do not even have any generic parameters so I am guessing that F# is instantiating new array types that inherit from the base `System.Array` on demand. I am drawing a blank on how to do it dynamically.

The reason why being able to move between my internal representation and the CLR types would be beneficial is because I am making a language that compiles to F# (in F#) and am using reflection functions such as `GetMethod` which take arrays of `System.Type`s as an argument. I am using them to do interop for lack of knowledge of any better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Type.MakeArrayType` to construct array types:

```
let rec to_dotnet_type: Ty -> System.Type = function
| Int32 -> typeof<Int32>
| Float32 -> typeof<Single>
| String -> typeof<String>
| Array(elemTy) -> let et = to_dotnet_type(elemTy) in et.MakeArrayType()
```

Comment: How would I do the reverse of that? How do I take a `System.Type` array and get its underlying type?

Comment: By using the `GetElementType` method. That answer my questions.